# 12.10 not working upon boot

Tags: 12.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 on a relatively old computer. It has a partitioned hard drive (shared with XP). Upon boot, I got a mouse, and a black screen. Also note that when i was upgrading, it said that a Unity plug in does not play nicely with my graphics card. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess your graphic card is just not fast enough for unity (because it is a compiz plugin thus not known as very resource saving)

i suggest you try some other ubuntu flavour with a more lightweight environment like [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) (XFCE) or [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) (LXDE)

regards, spheniscida